# New NSMutableDictionary with value from other NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSMutableDictionary with the following values

```
itemDictionary: {
    div = "Photo";
    id = "http://www.myurl.com/images/photo.php?category=images";
    summary = "Cool pictures";
    title = "Photographs";
    updated = Z;
}
```

What is the best way to Create a new dictionary with just the id value.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution seems pretty clear:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[itemDictionary objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I should really learn how to use the api documentation :-)